# Integral of the product of functions exists if integral of individual functions exist

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $f,g$ be real valued function on a subset $A$ of $\Bbb R^n$. Show that if $\int_A f$ and $\int_A g$ exist then $\int_A fg$ exists.

I proved that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable on a closed interval $I$ then so is $fg$ so far, how do I complete this?

Comment: You seem to be making a distinction between "$fg$ is integrable" and "$\int fg$ exists." Can you clarify what is the distinction?

Comment: I made a mistake, I proved $f,g$ are integrable over an arbitrary closed interval then $fg$ is integrable on it. I edited the question. Does this make sense?

Comment: You used the tag riemann-integration. How do you define the Riemann integral of a function on an arbitrary subset $A \subset \mathbb R^n$? I have only seen it defined for intervals. This is in contrast with the Lebesgue integral which can be calculated on any measurable set.

Comment: "Consider an arbitrary subset $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ and real valued function $f$ on some subset of $\Bbb R^n$ that contains $A$. define $\overline{f} (x) = f(x)$ if $x \in A, \overline{f}(x)=0$ if $x$ not in $A$. We say $f$ integrable on $A$ and define $\int_A f$ to be $\int_{\Bbb R^n} \overline{f}$ if the latter integral exists."

Comment: Note $\int_A f$ can only exist if the set of points $A$ at which $f$ is not zero is bounded and $f$ bounded on $A$

Comment: Does this clear things up?

Comment: OK, fair enough. Putting it another way, $\int_A f$ exists if and only if $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f \chi_A$ exists, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$. Let me think about a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $A \subset \mathbb R^n$. By definition (see comments under the question), this means that 
$$\int_A f = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f \chi_A$$
and
$$\int_A g = \int_{\mathbb R^n} g \chi_A$$
both exist. I take this to mean that both exist as *proper* Riemann integrals, so in particular, $f \chi_A$ and $g \chi_A$ are zero outside some closed bounded intervals $J$ and $K$ respectively. Let $I$ be a closed bounded interval containing $J$ and $K$. Then
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f \chi_A = \int_{I} f \chi_A$$
and
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} g \chi_A = \int_{I} g \chi_A$$
You have already proved the result for the case where the integral is taken over a closed bounded interval, so we can apply that result to the functions $f \chi_A$ and $g\chi_A$ to conclude that
$$\int_I (f \chi_A)(g\chi_A)$$
exists. Now note that
$$\int_I (f \chi_A)(g\chi_A) = \int_I fg\chi_A
= \int_{\mathbb R^n} fg\chi_A = \int_{A} fg$$

Comment: Thank you! Very simply put.